# People in the gym work out (missed correct adverb)

Tags: word-request

Some days ago I've said that "people in the gym work out **hardly**", then someone told me that when I say "**hardly**" in this context, then the meaning is in fact opposite of what I want to say (that their workout takes a lot of power).

Then my question is what is the *adverb* that can replace the incorrect *adverb* "hardly" to some other correct word in this context?

Comment: Contexts such as *He works [out] **hard**, Let's take it **easy**, Sleep **tight*** are what they call [flat adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb) (the adverbial form is the same as the adjectival one). Note that ***hardly*** has a completely different meaning *(not very much at all)*. Hence the "witticism" *How's your new job going? Are you **working hard** or **hardly working**?*

Comment: @Christophe Strobbe: Your understanding is incorrect. Item 10 on this list says [**Quick:** *This flat adverb is interchangeable with its normal equivalent: “Come quick” and “Come quickly” mean the same thing.*](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/) The only difference is that ***hardly*** and ***hard*** aren't normally interchangeable (or they *don't* normally mean the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjective "hard" is an exception to the rule that adverbs can be built from adjectives by adding "ly". So **"hard**" can be used both ***as an adjective and as an adverb***.

So your sentence should be

> People in the gym work out **hard**.

**Hardly** has various other meanings, e.g.

- I hardly know her. (I don't know her well at all.)
- You can hardly expect me to answer all the questions on ELL SE. (That would be unreasonable.)
- There's hardly any cheese left. (There is almost no cheese left.)

Here's an example of contrasting meanings:

- I'm tired because I've worked very **hard**.
- I have **hardly** worked, so I still have a lot of energy ;-) (= I have worked very little ...)

Also notice the different placement of hard and hardly.

The words `early, far, fast, late` can also be **both adjectives and adverbs**.
See the [Internet Grammar of English](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adverbs/adverbs.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then I can say also "very hard" in this context. Isn't it?

Comment: @Industrious Yes, you can say, "People in the gym work out very hard."

Answer (score 3):

The word *hard* may be both an adjective and adverb, the latter meaning "with effort, force or vigor", whereas *hardly* is an adverb meaning "almost not".